# TypeError: a(...).flexslider is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I updated my Wordpress install and the rev slider plugin that came with my theme stopped showing listings with multiple images.  I get this error: TypeError: a(...).flexslider is not a function

On this page: http://getorganicallysocial.com/deals/salud-juicery

The images are loading but the flexslider gallery is not loading properly.

The script code (Super heavy, I didn't write it!):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var MemberMouseGlobal = {"jsIsAdmin":"","adminUrl":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-admin\/","globalurl":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/membermouse","checkoutProcessingPaidMessage":"Please wait while we process your order...","checkoutProcessingFreeMessage":"Please wait while we create your account...","checkoutProcessingMessageCSS":"mm-checkout-processing-message","currencyInfo":{"currency":"USD","postfixIso":false,"name":"United States Dollar","int_curr_symbol":"&#85;&#83;&#68;&#32;","currency_symbol":"$","mon_decimal_point":".","mon_thousands_sep":",","mon_grouping":"3;3","positive_sign":"","negative_sign":"","int_frac_digits":"2","frac_digits":"2","p_cs_precedes":"1","p_sep_by_space":"0","n_cs_precedes":"1","n_sep_by_space":"0","p_sign_posn":"1","n_sign_posn":"1"}};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/resources/js/global.js?ver=2.2.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/resources/js/common/mm-common-core.js?ver=2.2.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/cc-circle-progress-bar/js/jquery.circliful.min.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/position.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/sortable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/menu.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/resizable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/draggable.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/button.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/dialog.min.js?ver=1.11.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var EM = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","locationajaxurl":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php?action=locations_search","firstDay":"1","locale":"en","dateFormat":"dd\/mm\/yy","ui_css":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/events-manager\/includes\/css\/ui-lightness.css","show24hours":"","is_ssl":"","bookingInProgress":"Please wait while the booking is being submitted.","tickets_save":"Save Ticket","bookingajaxurl":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","bookings_export_save":"Export Bookings","bookings_settings_save":"Save Settings","booking_delete":"Are you sure you want to delete?","bb_full":"Sold Out","bb_book":"Book Now","bb_booking":"Booking...","bb_booked":"Booking Submitted","bb_error":"Booking Error. Try again?","bb_cancel":"Cancel","bb_canceling":"Canceling...","bb_cancelled":"Cancelled","bb_cancel_error":"Cancellation Error. Try again?","txt_search":"Search","txt_searching":"Searching...","txt_loading":"Loading..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/events-manager/includes/js/events-manager.js?ver=5.55'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var geodir_var = {"siteurl":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com","geodir_plugin_url":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/geodirectory","geodir_ajax_url":"http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php?action=geodir_ajax_action","geodir_gd_modal":"1","is_rtl":"0"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/geodirectory/geodirectory-assets/js/geodirectory.min.js?ver=1.4.5' async='async'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/geodirectory/geodirectory-assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/geodirectory/geodirectory-assets/js/ajax-chosen.min.js?ver=1.4.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/ignitiondeck-crowdfunding/js/jquery.ddslick.min.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var id_ajaxurl = "\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php";
var id_siteurl = "http:\/\/getorganicallysocial.com\/";
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/ignitiondeck-crowdfunding/js/ignitiondeck.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/ignitiondeck-crowdfunding/js/idlightbox.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/ignitiondeck/js/idf-lite.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/resources/js/user/mm-preview.js?ver=2.2.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=4.6.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=4.6.5'></script>
```

The HTML code:

```
    <div class="project-header">
                <div class="flexslider mini">
                                <ul class="slides">

                                <li class="slide"><img src="http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/SaludJuiceryDealImage-845x573.jpg" width="845" height="573" alt="" /></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/salud1-845x573.jpg" width="845" height="573" alt="" /></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="http://getorganicallysocial.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/salud2-845x573.jpg" width="845" height="573" alt="" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>


                </div>
```

I don't see multiple jquery calls, but maybe it is too much script for the page to handle properly?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks, 
Mary

Comment: its either of 2 things. 1) the flexslider.js is no longer being loaded (most likely as it was the update that caused the issue). Just enqueue it again if you cant find the code for it in those scripts.   2) the flexslider code is loaded after scripts.min.js (its not)

Comment: The flexslider is being called in the last two lines...maybe that is the issue?

Comment: no i don't see a flexslider.js file being loaded. Flexslider is not defined means it doesn't exist at the time it was run so unless the code is in one of the js files being loaded, its not there (it could be).

Comment: Okay - I went through and apparently the original developer changed the class name for some reason. I restored a backup to get it to work again.  Thanks for taking a look!